# I am creating reactjs application using create-react-app .but when I am trying npm start .It it showing this error

Tags: reactjs

I have tried to update webpack but then it is showing the same error with another required dependency version.
[image]

Comment: Can you follow the instructions what is in your terminal? 
1.
2.
.
.
7

Comment: @webHasan I tried these.                                                                                                     C:\Users\harshit pandey\Desktop\myreact>npm ls webpack
myreact@0.1.0 C:\Users\harshit pandey\Desktop\myreact
`-- react-scripts@2.0.5
  `-- webpack@4.19.1

Answer (score 0):

You have installed webpack globally. Try 
`npm uninstall - g webpack`.
And then delete the node modules folder of your application. Delete your package.lock file. 
Do an `npm install`

Comment: I tried these steps, but it is showing the same error.